# how to build the microsoft seal library in ubuntu and make any project from that?

Tags: ubuntu, build, cryptography, seal

I am trying to build the latest version of the Microsoft SEAL library on ubuntu but as given in the documentation on the GitHub page I'm able the make only sealexample and the sealtest executable file from it. I've to write a custom program using this library but can't figure out how to start with this.

I've tried using linking the library as seal/seal.h which is available in the code but it didn't work.

please suggest the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install SEAL according to the instructions in `README.md` (sounds like you already did that). Then just create a new directory with your project source files, create a new `CMakeLists.txt` similar to `native/examples/CMakeLists.txt`, and run

```
cmake .
make
```

in your directory. For an example, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vJJMU2gMn4.

Comment: Now, This method is infeasible for SEAL 3.6.1. Your video is unuseful. Could you give me newer method?

Comment: The [README.md](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/main/README.md#linking-with-microsoft-seal-through-cmake) has a pretty detailed description of what to do. Is there some specific thing there that is unclear?

Comment: @KimLaine on running `make -j` ,nothing can be seen on terminal screen  but the command terminates and i cannot find `libseal.a` file.

Comment: @Land did you find anything?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/microsoft-seal/#!videos

Comment: Probably the easiest way today to install and use SEAL is by installing it with [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).